# Where can I find beginner resources on using voltage regulators with Arduino circuits?

Tags: voltage-level, servo, electronics

I'm trying to concurrently learn electronics and Arduino, and have recently moved from simply powering LEDs to servos. In all my attempts with servos and reading about them (especially multiple ones, and when using external power supply plugged into the board), experienced users often mention you use voltage regulators.

I've seen some Arduino schematics with servos and voltage regulators, most that include some capacitors, but I can't seem to find any tutorials or resources that explain why, when and how to use these parts when learning electronics & Arduino. (I'd like to go from there to transistors, mosfets, etc.)

Comment: Try reading the datasheet of the regulator you want to use. Most supply a sample circuit with recommended capacitor values. Datasheets can be scary, but you don't need to understand everything. Come time, you'll begin to know the meaning of more and more values inside any datasheet. At least, this is what happened (and is still happening) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the capacitors smooth the signals. This helps the internal workings of the regulator not overshoot when compensating for a change in the input or the output. If the capacitors are not there then there is a chance of oscillation.

A search of google for Voltage Regulator Tutorial will give you quite a few results, here is one that I found (obviously this could change so if it does just do a search and go from there)

[regulator basics](http://www.baldengineer.com/tutorials/regulator-basics/)

The link above is a good explanation that is not too in depth. But as stated in the comments look at the datasheet for specific values needed.

I also did a search for 'what are the capacitors for on a voltage regulator' and found some good info about why they are needed.

Comment: You are missing a link or something in your answer. When you update it, please include some valuable information in your answer instead of just linking to another website.

Comment: @sachleen, sorry it is not up to your standards but Gregir has asked for links to good tutorials I have supplied him with one. If you click on the words 'regulator basics' you will find the info requested (I hope).

Comment: It's not @sachleen's standards, it's common sense. Links change or pages disappear. So a future visitor may not get the information. Including some useful information or excerpts from the link(s) you supply means your post continues to be useful regardless of what happens to external resources. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Good search suggestions here. Not sure why my Google efforts were so fruitless, but I'm starting to find more info now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a smooth signal to your power regulator you should use some capacitors before and after the voltage regulator. It will look something like this when you use the 7805 voltage regulator.

[image: 7805 Voltage Regulator]

Note: This schematic is from a dutch website. Uin means Vin and Uuit means Vout. C2 and C3 are bipolar capacitors.

It's also smart to put a diode before the voltage regulator to make sure the voltage flows only to one direction. The values of C1, C2, C3 and C4 and pretty standard and coul be used for the other Voltage regulators as well.

The voltage Regulators come in different fixed values and tey have a minimum and maximum voltage they can handle. Here's a small table of the most common VR's with their minimum input voltages.

```
Part Number     Output Voltage (V)      Minimum Input Voltage (V)
7805            +5                      7.3
7806            +6                      8.3
7808            +8                      10.5
7809            +9                      11.5
7810            +10                     12.5
7812            +12                     14.6
7815            +15                     17.7
7818            +18                     21.0
7824            +24                     27.1
```

Also note that the output currents of these Voltage Regulators listed above is max 1A. When they're called like 78S05 or 78S09 it'll be a 2A Voltage Regulator.

Another thing that could be important when you're using the minimum input voltages. If you put a diode before the Voltage Regulator there will be a small voltage drop. For a 1N4007 the voltage drop will be around the 0.5V. The voltage drop will only occur before the voltage regulator though, so when you don't use the minimal input values you don't have to mind about it.

Comment: Thanks. Calling out the diode and minimum input voltage stuff is helpful. I missed/glossed over that stuff before.